chrome_crashpad_handler crashing constantly while VS Code is open with Python project (macOS)
I'm working on a plug-in for Autodesk Fusion, which can be written in Python or C++. Fusion integrates with VS Code for this development, and you can debug the plug-in as it runs in Fusion.
I just started this a couple days ago. I haven't used VS Code in some time. But chrome_crashpad_handler, down inside VS Code’s embedded Electron framework (i.e. Visual Studio Code.app/Contents/Frameworks/Electron Framework.framework/Versions/A/Helpers/chrome_crashpad_handler). It comes in waves, but it’ll crash a dozen times over the course of a few seconds, then settle down, then start up again. This happens while VS Code is open (so far I’ve tried it with two different Python projects open, one the Fusion plug-in, the other something else I’m working on). It doesn’t matter if Fusion is running or not.
I’ve found one discussion of this, but no real resolution. I’m not sure if it’s a VS Code bug or an Electron bug.
Exception Type:        EXC_BREAKPOINT (SIGTRAP)
Exception Codes:       0x0000000000000001, 0x0000000100b49a20

Thread 0 Crashed::  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
0   chrome_crashpad_handler                0x100b49a20 CrashpadHandlerMain + 98344
1   chrome_crashpad_handler                0x100b494a0 CrashpadHandlerMain + 96936
2   chrome_crashpad_handler                0x100b6ca64 CrashpadHandlerMain + 241772
3   chrome_crashpad_handler                0x100b6ca7c CrashpadHandlerMain + 241796
4   chrome_crashpad_handler                0x100b3a45c CrashpadHandlerMain + 35428
5   chrome_crashpad_handler                0x100b37d80 CrashpadHandlerMain + 25480
6   chrome_crashpad_handler                0x100b31aa4 CrashpadHandlerMain + 172
7   dyld                                   0x18d28f154 start + 2476

I’m not really sure what else to try. I’m on the latest version of VS Code.
Version: 1.93.1
Commit: 38c31bc77e0dd6ae88a4e9cc93428cc27a56ba40
Date: 2024-09-11T17:20:05.685Z
Electron: 30.4.0
ElectronBuildId: 10073054
Chromium: 124.0.6367.243
Node.js: 20.15.1
V8: 12.4.254.20-electron.0
OS: Darwin arm64 23.6.0

Any suggestions as to what I can do to stop fix this? Is anyone else encountering this? Each crash writes a log. I have hundreds over the last couple of days.

Notably Opera 89 uses chrome_crashpad_handler.

I don't believe I have Opera installed anywhere.
